# How can I use jQuery to increment a table cell by 1 each time the button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell, increment

Here is my html:

```
<table class="myTable" summary="Table with ages">       
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>            
    </tr>   

    <tr>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td id="joesAge">35</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Becky</td>
        <td id="beckysAge">40</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Joey</td>
        <td id="joeysAge">50</td>
    </tr>                   
</table>

<button onclick="add">Add</button>
```

I need the cells joesAge, beckysAge and joeysAge to each increment by 1 each time the add button is clicked. Can someone assist me please?

Comment: Hello Michelle, please make sure you've posted what you've tried.

Comment: I have edited your post so that your HTML is better formatted. If you are able to post the jQuery that you've tried already, I'm sure someone will be able to help you out with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add(){

    // solution
    // get the row you want
    // get the value, parseInt it and increment by 1
    // replace the content of the row by incremented value

    var joesAgeTd = document.getElementById("joesAge");
    var newJoesAge = parseInt(joesAgeTd.innerHTML) + 1;
    joesAgeTd.innerHTML = newJoesAge;

    var beckysAgeTd = document.getElementById("beckysAge");
    var newbeckysAge = parseInt(beckysAgeTd.innerHTML) + 1;
    beckysAgeTd.innerHTML = newbeckysAge;

    var joeysAgeTd = document.getElementById("joeysAge");
    var newjoeysAge = parseInt(joeysAgeTd.innerHTML) + 1;
    joeysAgeTd.innerHTML = newjoeysAge;
}
</script>
<table class="myTable" summary="Table with ages">
    <tr>
        <th >Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td id="joesAge">35</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Becky</td>
        <td id="beckysAge">40</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Joey</td>
        <td id="joeysAge">50</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyfgo40z/) displaying my example solution.

```
$(function () {

    $(document).on('click', 'button', function () {

      var userId = ['#joesAge', '#beckysAge', '#joeysAge'];

      $.each(userId, function (index, value) {

         var age = parseInt($(value).text(), 10);

         if (age) {
             $(value).text(age + 1);
         }

      });
   });
});
```

I have used an `.on('click')` event to bind the button click, I have also hard coded the `td` element Id's which could (should) be written to handle **any** element id in a table which contained the word "Age" for example.

**UPDATE**

```
$(function () {

// bind button click:
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {

    // array for IDs:
    var items = [];

    // find all TD ID's which contains "Age":
    $(".myTable tr td[id*='Age']").each(function() {

        var id = $(this).attr('id');            

        if(id) {   
            // add *Age IDs ready to be incremented:  
            items.push('#' + id);
        }

     });

    // Loop through all ID's and increment by 1:
    $.each(items, function (index, value) {

        var age = parseInt($(value).text(), 10);

        if (age) {
            $(value).text(age + 1);
        }
    });
});
});
```

I have updated my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/ju53xf0n/) which handles any `td` element with an attribute Id containing the word "Age"